# Async replication of non-root owned database in ArangoDB

Tags: javascript, database-replication, arangodb

I'm trying to async replicate an ArangoDB database owned by a non-root user (i.e. without access to the _system collection).
I've been able to successfully perform the replication (although the graphs are not replicated..) operating as root as described in the ArangoDB docs asynchronous replication example. but I'd like to accomplish this as some other user.

On both the master (master.domain) and the slave (slave.domain) db instances, I created the user "user" (password "userpwd"), owning a database "testdb".
On the master I created a few document collections, an edge collection, and a graph connecting those, and I saved some documents in the collections.
I'm running ArangoDB 3.2.4 on debian amd64 stretch vms, both for master and slave.

This is the arangosh script I use to start the replication:

setupReplication.js:

```
// Import replication module
const replication = require("@arangodb/replication");

// Define replication parameters
const targetDatabase = "testdb";
const replicationParams = {
  endpoint: "ssl://master.domain:8530",
  username: "user",
  password: "userpwd",
  includeSystem: false,
  incremental: true,
  autoResync: true,
  autoStart: true,
  verbose: false,
};

// Set active database
db._useDatabase(targetDatabase);

// Start continuous replication
console.log("Starting continuous replication");
replication.setupReplication(replicationParams);
```

If I run the script as "user", i.e. with:

```
arangosh --javascript.execute setupReplication.js --server.endpoint 
ssl://slave.domain:8530 --server.username user
```

I get the error:

> 2017-10-12T16:52:41Z [9306] ERROR JavaScript exception in file
> '/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/replication.js' at
> 179,7: ArangoError 11: forbidden 2017-10-12T16:52:41Z [9306] ERROR !
> throw err; 2017-10-12T16:52:41Z [9306] ERROR !

which seems to fail because "user" is unauthorized (forbidden).

If I run the script as "root", i.e. with:

```
arangosh --javascript.execute setupReplication.js --server.endpoint 
ssl://slave.domain:8530 --server.username root
```

The script runs without errors and I see this in the slave's logs:

> 2017-10-12T16:59:28Z [18013] INFO {replication} started replication
> applier for database 'testdb', endpoint 'ssl://master.domain:8530'
> from tick 33742 2017-10-12T16:59:28Z [18013] INFO {replication}
> connected to master at ssl://master.domain:8530, id 26189759765235,
> version 3.2, last log tick 33742

So this would suggest the replication started, but when I look into the slave's database using the web interface, I see nothing has been replicated to the slave (no collections, no graph).

If I run the script with targetDatabase = "_system", both as "user" and as "root", I get an "Unauthorized" error like:

> 2017-10-12T17:11:29Z [9460] ERROR JavaScript exception in file
> '/usr/share/arangodb3/js/client/modules/@arangodb/arangosh.js' at
> 98,7: ArangoError 401: Unauthorized 2017-10-12T17:11:29Z [9460] ERROR
> !      throw error; 2017-10-12T17:11:29Z [9460] ERROR !

Any idea if/how this kind of replication can be accomplished?